# Expo: Integrity could not be verified

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, diawi

I just built a react native app using expo for my iOs device using `expo build:ios`.
Once I got the .ipa file created, I decided to upload it on diawi, because I had to share the build with my client and also learnt that you could not install an .ipa by running it directly on an iOs device.

The thing is when I'm trying to install it via diawi, I get this error ***Unable to install [app name]: this app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified***.

I tried to reinstall it multiple times, I also went to the settings on my device under the  *VPN & Device Management* section but there is no profile showing up here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Don't build it using the normal build command.. Use an `ad-hoc` profile to build it .
AdHoc profile registers the specified iPhone for demo and internal testing and verifies the installation.

I also went through the same but found the solution after days of struggle.

Here are the docs - https://docs.expo.dev/build/internal-distribution/#setting-up-ad-hoc-provisioning